# Does change handle migration / rolling back of schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

In the new preferred way, there is only 1 method which seems to add a column. Does that mean you don't need to have a method to remove columns?

```
# the old way
class AddNameToPerson < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :persons, :name, :string
  end

  def down
    remove_column :person, :name
  end
end

# the new prefered way
class AddNameToPerson < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :persons, :name, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the magic of Rails 3.1 and later. Rails knows how to migrate your database and reverse it when the migration is rolled back without the need to write a separate down method.

Rails keep track of migration. So it will have the implementation for reverse the changes added by the migration when you `roll back`. Earlier we use to have two methods `up` and `down`. On Rails 3.1 and later they changed migration to have `change` method.

In case of `add_coulmn` reverse method is `remove_column` and same for other methods. Using tracked detail it will call appropriate action. So you don't need two methods(`up` and `down`). You can see the methods supported by `change` method: [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method). If you have other then these method you need to use `up` and `down`.

If you are confused with using `change` method then I suggest you to use `up` and `down`. Once you thorough with migration you can start using `change` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, You don't need a separate method to remove columns.

You can even try 'rake db:rollback' and then again 'rake db:migrate' if you don't have any data to lose.

It works perfectly. :)